# Как разрешить использовать команду только 1 раз в день?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как разрешить пользователю использовать команду только 1 раз? Например, чтобы 1 раз в день он мог написать 'hello world'.

```py
if input() == 'команда':
    print('hello world')
```

Comment: Никак. Если у пользователя есть доступ к выполнению произвольных исполняемых файлов и скриптов, он сможет делать что угодно в обход любых ваших ограничений

Comment: @andreymal я про команду в боте. У пользователя нет доступа к файлам

Comment: Значит записывайте куда-нибудь дату последнего выполнения команды, а перед следующим выполнениям считывайте и сравнивайте с текущей датой

Comment: ок, спасибо. через datetime это возможно сделать?